# Eclipse CDT - new template or "project type"

Tags: templates, eclipse-cdt

Using Eclipse Helios and CDT 7.

Is it possible to save a project as a new template/project type?

When you go to create a new project, a dialog opens and you select a project type (Executable -> empty project, etc.)  I would like to add one.

Point is, I'm playing with SDL, and I know I'll be making a lot of new projects.  I don't want to have to go into the preferences each time and set up the compiler/linker to find the files.

I've been looking for a while, but have had no luck finding anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do what you want. Check out the link [How to Register Templates](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/projectTemplateEngine/Howtoregistertemplates.html).  I created the following plugin using the instructions in the previous link. [Download Plugin](http://instructor.uat.edu/csc/phartley/edu.uat.cs.cpp.cpptemplate_0.0.1.jar).