# How to make Eclipse/Ant aware of Cygwin without adding to global path

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, cygwin

I have a Java project in Eclipse, running on Windows. It uses ANT and has a target which invokes Linux tools like SCP/BASH. I've installed cygwin but since I haven't added it to my global path, Eclipse/ANT isn't aware.

Where/how should I make individual projects aware that my cygwin/bin dir should be on their path?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you should set up an ant or program config in your [Tools -> External tools] config. This wouldn't work on a project-by-project basis though.

Regarding doing it on a project-by-project basis though, I'm not really sure if you can. Ordinarily, the project tool-chain is determined by the project type you select. That is, you select [New -> Java Project] and you're provided with config to configure the JRE to use, etc.

So, I suspect that to do what you're asking on a project-by-project basis, you'd need to create a new Eclipse project template. This means creating a plugin for your new project-type that will allow you to configure your environment configured with the toolchain you want.

I'm not an expert but this post may be helpful: [Eclipse CDT - new template or "project type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863988/eclipse-cdt-new-template-or-project-type).